# Is it possible to host a shiny app that calls out to a python script to generate data?

Tags: python-3.x, shiny, web-hosting, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have a Python script and a Shiny app. The shiny app calls out run a python(3) command based on arguments generated in the app. The python script generates simulation data which is plotted in the shiny app.

My problem is that I don't know how to host this app, since it has both python and R dependencies. Usually I would go with PythonAnywhere, and after poking around a little it seems that shinyappio is also inappropriate (I tried uploading and the server doesn't recognize the `python` command). Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to have a look at library([reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/)) and [digital ocean](https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/).

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- I'm a bit confused about your comment "the server doesn't recognize the python command", as Python is definitely installed :-)  Where are you seeing that error?

Comment: @GilesThomas this was on the Shinyappio server, not PythonAnywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reticulate is a great option. Another way is to create a Python container on Azure (ACN) that outputs the Python data as json. You can then connect to the Azure Python output using httr and jsonlite packages from within Shinyapps. This tutorial is very helpful on how the Python script can be set up and hosted. https://github.com/CSA-OCP-GER/azure-machine-learning-bootcamp/blob/master/hints/challenge_03.md